# Как понять, кто из пользователей является админом в чате телеграмма?

Tags: telegram

Я пишу приложение для телеграмма, и я не могу понять, как определить какие пользователи являются админами в чате? Я использую метод messages.getFullChat https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getFullChat  для получения всех всех пользователей чата. Данные приходят в следующем формате:

```
[ { _: 'user',
flags: 2171,
contact: true,
id: 308452873,
access_hash: '9950118122100162821',
first_name: 'Dugarry',
username: 'iwilldoit88',
phone: '380990108863',
photo: 
 { _: 'userProfilePhoto',
   photo_id: '1324795002348480425',
   photo_small: 
    { _: 'fileLocation',
      dc_id: 2,
      volume_id: '223024924',
      local_id: 417467,
      secret: '177921745850179414' },
   photo_big: 
    { _: 'fileLocation',
      dc_id: 2,
      volume_id: '223024924',
      local_id: 417469,
      secret: '7026522777044114568' } },
status: { _: 'userStatusOffline', was_online: 1508030678 } },
```

Но тут не ясно, кто из них админы. Может кто-то предложить способ для получения админов чата?

Comment: Вот же `id` админа - `id: 308452873`. [If the chat is a group or a supergroup and no administrators were appointed, only the creator will be returned.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators)

Comment: и как вы поняли что это админ, а не участник чата?

Comment: я же написал, если чат - супергруппа, то возвращается только создатель чата, в случае success

Comment: вы точно про апи для приложений говорити? ничего не путаете?